# Echo or sh methods doesnt work in jenkins classes from shared libraries

Tags: class, jenkins, inheritance, shared-libraries

I used functions placed in /vars/ of shared libraries and they worked fine. But i need to use classes now. To learn it I made some 2 simple classes (parent and its child) to get some git info.

/src/ptx/shared/GitInfo.groovy

```
package ptx.shared

class GitInfo implements Serializable{
    public String commandMsg
    public String commandId
    public String commandAuthor
    public String msg
    public String id 
    public String author
    def steps

    public GitInfo(steps){
        this.steps = steps
        this.commandMsg = "git log --format=%B -n 1"
        this.commandId =  "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%h'"
        this.commandAuthor = "git log -n 1 --format=%ae"
        this.msg = this.runCommand(this.commandMsg)
        this.id = this.runCommand(this.commandId)
        this.author = this.runCommand(this.commandAuthor)
    }

    @NonCPS
    public runCommand(command){
    }
}
```

src/ptx/shared/LinuxGitInfo.groovy

```
package ptx.shared
//import ptx.shared.GitInfo

class LinuxGitInfo extends GitInfo {
    public LinuxGitInfo(steps){
        super(steps)
    }
    @NonCPS
    public runCommand(command){
        echo "something"
        //return this.steps.sh(script: command, returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
}
```

and my pipeline

```
@Library('firstlibrary') _
import ptx.shared.*

pipeline{
    agent { label 'agents'}
    //libraries{
    //    lib('firstlibrary')
    //}
    environment{
        GIT_CREDS = credentials('gitlab')
    }
    stages{
        stage('git'){
            steps{
                git 'http://' + env.GIT_CREDS + '@10.11.22.112/root/pytest.git'
            }
        }
        stage('lib functions'){
            steps{
                script{
                    //first.mySh('pwd')
                    def gitinfo = new LinuxGitInfo(this)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But im getting this

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ptx.shared.LinuxGitInfo.echo() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [something]
Possible solutions: each(groovy.lang.Closure), getAt(java.lang.String), wait(), grep(), dump(), any()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
...
```

With sh() is the same. What im missing?

Answer (score 2):

Methods marked `@NonCPS` can't use the built in steps: 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/README.md#technical-design

You can use groovy command `println` there, or remove the annotation.